# Can any torsion-free abelian group be embedded in a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to solve this for a problem and I need to know if what I have done is right:

Let $B$ be a torsion-free abelian group. Then we consider the set $$A=\{(b,n):b\in B,n\in \mathbb Z,n\neq 0\}$$ and define 
$$(b,n)\sim (a,m) \text{ iff } bm=an.$$ 
This yields an equivalence relation, now you can define addition of classes by $(b,n)+(a,m)=(am+bn,nm)$. Then $(A,+)$ is a torsion-free abelian group and $B$ can be embedded into $(A,+)$, but also $(A,+)$ is divisible, so $(A,+)$ can be embedded in a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should also know that $(A,+)$ torsion-free and divisible implies it is *uniquely* divisible (for any $a\in A$ and $n\in{\bf Z}$ nonzero there is precisely one $\bar{a}$ such that $n\bar{a}=a$; check that this allows a well-defined action of $\bf Q$) and hence it is a $\bf Q$-vector space.

Comment: Not only can your $A$ be embedded in a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$, it's actually isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$. As anon said, $A$ has the structure of a $\mathbb  Q$-vector space.  Any vector space (over any field) has a basis, which gives you an isomorphism to a direct sum (indexed by the basis) of copies of the field.

Comment: How can I embed $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$ in a direct sum of some $\mathbb{Q}$'s?

Comment: @AshGX The product is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, so it has a basis (if you assume the axiom of choice).

Comment: The construction you're doing is exactly the same as building $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}Q$.

Comment: @РодионРаскольников: Another method can be found in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/425493/36434

Comment: Just to add to Seirios's comment: this question has already been asked and answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/425431/221).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using tensor products, inspired in egreg's comment above.

By corollary 4.27 in [this expository article by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf), the map $B\to B\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$, $b\mapsto b\otimes 1$ is injective, since $B$ is torsion-free. Now, the abelian group $B\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure (it is the $\mathbb{Q}$-extension of scalars of $B$), hence it is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$.